# Why isn't quiet boot.. quiet? (Ubuntu 22.10)

Tags: boot, grub2

it is a minor "problem" but I don't understand why I don't have quiet boot on despite having the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in the /etc/default/grub file (which was by default, I haven't edited anything)
To be more clear, [that's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uK66.jpg) (sorry for the terrible pic, but I can't screenshot during boot)
Isn't that what should happen without the quiet option?
Thanks in advance if anyone can clarify this
The output to `cat /proc/cmdline` is this:

> BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.0.9-060009-generic
> root=UUID=1e0be401-da74-4b41-91ad-bfa72d115837 ro console=tty12 quiet
> splash vt.handoff=7

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what file you mean (`/etc` is a directory with several hundred or thousand files) and ii) show us exactly what you have in that file. Also tell us if you just edited the file or if you also ran `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: Please also [edit] in the output from `cat /proc/cmdline`